# AWS SES Email Sending (Delivery Failure)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, email-validation

I have been under attack by email spammer via my AWS SES and therefor AWS put my account under review due to high complaint rate.

The email is still getting sent out.

This is the first time that it happen to me. Can someone please advise what should I have to do.

Thanks.

Comment: 1) change / delete the SES user to stop the spam -- those credentials might be stolen now  2) figure out how they either broke into your server, or used a design flaw to send spam.  If your server was not hacked, you might have email forms where the form processing code allows sending anything to anyone because you trust the client side.  Never trust that what a client sends will be what you expect -- with code you can send anything not  just what your HTML and JavaScript says to send.

Comment: Thanks @DaveS I really appreciate it. 
I just found out our IAM access key has been stolen. In a process of emergency rotation.